# Appscript to get hyperlink to another google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a code that will help me to find the hyperlink of another google sheet on my google drive, everything i have read explains how to get the link for the active sheet..

any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DriveApp` with functions [getFilesByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename) or [getFilesByType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbytypemimetype). Then provide file id to [SpreadsheetApp.openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid).

Answer (score 0):

#### This look will give you the hyperlink to every sheet in a spreadsheet

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheets().forEach(s =>
      tree.txt.push([ `=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${file.getId()}/edit#gid=${s.getSheetId()}","${s.getName()}")`]));
```

It generates a column.  It's just a fragment of a piece of code

Answer (score 0):

I have something a bit more simple to apply. The code below goes into the Drive folder and list down every file (doc/sheets/pdf etc) and its hyperlink.

All you will need to change is your tab name to store the folder details and your Gdrive folder ID.

If you want to extract folders within a folder in the future you can switch `getFiles()` to `getFolders()`.

```
function folderitems(){
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet 1'); //Edit tab name to list the folder details

  const parentFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById('INPUT FOLDER ID HERE'); //Input Gdrive ID here
  const contents=parentFolder.getFiles();
  ss.appendRow(['name','link']);

  while (contents.hasNext()){
    var file = contents.next();
    var name=file.getName();
    var link=file.getUrl();
    ss.appendRow([name,link]);
  }
}
```

Outcome should look something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### To retrieve the URL of one spreadsheet by script

```
function getFileUrl() {
  var nameOfFile = 'your file name'
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(nameOfFile);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    console.log (file.getUrl())
  }
}
```